# Using Ktor, how do I deserialize JSON responses with lists of different types?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, ktor

I am working on an Android app that uses Ktor for HTTP requests to an API. Depending upon the query, the response may contain a list of one of two types. The code works when I define four data classes: One each for the response types and two different result data classes -- one for each result type. However, I would like to know if it's possible to use only one response data class and tell it which data class to use for the list when I make the HTTP request.

I'm using the Kotlin serialization libaray

The classes look like the following:

`

```
@Serializable
data class ResultOne(
    val count: Int,
    val result: List<TypeOne>
)

@Serializable
data class ResultTwo(
    val count: Int,
    val result: List<Type2>
)

@Serializable
data class TypeOne(
   val str1: String,
   val str2: String,
   val int1: Int
)

@Serializable
data class TypeTwo(
    val str1: String,
    val dbl1: Double,
    val int1: Int
)
```

And the request looks something like this:

```
...
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.json
...


private val httpClient = HttpClient {    
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json{
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })
    }
}


fun getResultTypeOne(){
    val response = responseOne(listOf(1, 2)).result
}


private suspend fun responseOne(ints: List<Int>): ResultOne {
    val availableShows = httpClient.get("https://my.api.com/search")
    return availableShows.body()
}

fun getResultTypeTwo(){
    val response = responseTwo(listOf(1, 2)).result
}


private suspend fun responseTwo(ints: List<Int>): ResultTwo {
    val availableShows = httpClient.get("https://my.api.com/search")
    return availableShows.body()
}
```

There's a bit of redundancy in the HTTP calls, as they are the same with the exception of specifying a different data class for the difference result types. Is there a way to instead reuse the same HTTP call, but tell it which result type to expect in that call?

Comment: Is `Str` type supposed to be `String`?

Comment: It is, yes. I'm used to coding in Python. In the actual code, it's written as String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is possible. You should replace your `ResultOne` and `ResultTwo` classes with one generic class:

```
@Serializable
data class Result <T> (
   val count: Int,
   val result: T
)
```

This way, you can reuse your `Result` class for both `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo`, and your HTTP requests can be simplified:

```
private val httpClient = HttpClient {    
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json{
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })
    }
}


fun getResultOne(){
    val response = response<TypeOne>(listOf(1, 2)).result
}

fun getResultTwo(){
    val response = response<TypeTwo>(listOf(1, 2)).result
}

private suspend fun <T> response(ints: List<Int>): Result<T> {
    val availableShows = httpClient.get("https://my.api.com/search")
    return availableShows.body()
}
```

If you have other questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: It's taken me a long time to get back to this, but thanks for the response. The only thing I had to change was in the Result class, make `val result` return a list: `val result: List<T>`